# Queries about rejection

Tags: visas, indian-citizens

I was 10 years old when I visited US for the very first time. My mother, my sister and I didn't overstay but my biological father overstayed at that time. However, he expired in the year 2009. He overstayed in US. We reapplied for a US tourist visa in the year 2017. As my biological father overstayed in US our visa got rejected. My mother remarried. My step father was interrogated personally by the higher visa authorities. The visa officer said that as our biological father overstayed so there might be a possibility that my step father might overstay. They refused to give us the visa.

EDIT: My father expired just after months of his return to India.He expired in India.He overstayed in USA from 2004 to 2008.

My question is: Can I reapply in the near future? Will there be chances of rejection again?

Comment: what year did your father overstay? what nationality do you all have? did your father pass away in the US or your homecountry?

Comment: All you can do is try, but the more recently you were rejected and the more often you have been rejected, the less likely you are to get a positive response.

Comment: @CGCampbell I've posted the comment as a full answer.  I didn't feel it got into enough depth to qualify as a proper answer.

Answer (score 2):

All you can do is try, but the more recently you were rejected and the more often you have been rejected, the less likely you are to get a positive response.